# How to use a Notary client to access IBM Cloud notary server

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry

I got the following error when trying to use a Notary client to get the digest of a signed image in my IBM Container Registry. Can anyone advise how to solve it?

```
# notary -s https://us.icr.io:4443 lookup us.icr.io/securek8s/hello-world latest

* fatal: unauthorized: The login credentials are not valid, or your IBM Cloud account is not active.
```

BTW, I built the Notary client from https://github.com/theupdateframework/notary

Answer (score 0):

Notary uses your credentials from your Docker login cache. The error message that you received suggests that your login to `us.icr.io` isn't valid. This usually means that your credentials have expired.

If you have the `ibmcloud` CLI and the `container-registry` plugin installed, you can refresh your login by making sure that you're targeting the US South registry (`ibmcloud cr region-set us.icr.io`) and then logging in with `ibmcloud cr login`.

If you don't have the CLI plugin installed, you can log in using Docker commands directly. For more information, see [Automating access to IBM Cloud Container Registry](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-registry_access#registry_access_user_apikey)
 in the IBM Cloud docs.